# JavaScript: Check if variable exist without classic if()

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

i've got the following situation.

In my script I have extracted all strings, that are publicated to the webpage, into an object like this.

```
var strings = {
    one: "One",
    two: "Two",
    three: "Three",
}
```

Please don't ask why I want to do this, it's just a test case.

Now I want to push one of these strings, for example, into an alert(). this would look like this:

```
alert(strings.one);
```

So far so good, but I want to check if strings or strings.one exist and when it doesn't return an empty string.

What is a slick way to do this, without using the classic `if(strings.one == undefined)`?

### EDIT

I've found a solution according to your answers and comments.

```
alert((window.strings) ? strings.one || "nope" : "nope");
```

This catches all cases i want to prevent:

1. I forgot to declare `strings`
2. `strings.one` doesn't exists

I hope this fits to "slick way"?!

Comment: You're looking for a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). Also check [short-circuit operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `||`, which returns the first operand if it's truthy and the second otherwise:

```
alert(strings.one || "");
```

This will also catch other falsy values, but that probably won't be an issue for you.

Comment: Is there any computational advantage to doing this?

Comment: I've done it, but I think I've forgotten something. I debug my code with the Chrome Developer Tools and when I put the variable into watch expressions it returns <not available>. It's correct that || doesn't help me in this case?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator or u can do this if you want and empty string if string.one does not exist.

```
alert(string.one || '');
```